# How do I upload a Python package to Azure Artifacts without having to open the device login page and enter in the auth code?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, twine

Does anyone know how I can upload a Python package through Azure DevOps/Pipelines to the artifact feed, without having to open the device login page, and enter in the auth code each time?

Currently, my pipeline runs fine where it builds the Python package, runs through the pipeline, and uploads in to the Artifacts feed.

The only problem is that every time, I have to monitor the "Upload Package" step, click on the "https://microsoft.com/devicelogin" and enter in the code to authenticate to upload the package.

[image]

Is there an automated way to do this?

Here is my .yml file below, thank you for your help!

```
trigger:
- master
- pipeline*

parameters:
- name: path
  type: string
  default: 'dist/*.whl'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.10'
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.10'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    pip install twine keyring artifacts-keyring
    python -m pip install --upgrade build setuptools twine
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: |
    python -m build
  displayName: 'Build Python Package'

- task: TwineAuthenticate@1
  inputs:
    artifactFeed: 'MyApp/myapp-packages'
  displayName: 'Authenticate Twine'

- script: |
    python -m twine upload -r insite-packages --repository-url https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/kngwin/MyApp/_packaging/myapp-packages/pypi/upload/ --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) dist/*
  displayName: 'Upload Package'
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

After following Kim's answer below, where I tried both methods of creating a .pypirc file in my ~Home directory, and also adding the token in the URL. I am still receiving a request for User Interaction, to open the device login page and enter in the code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
trigger:
- master
- pipeline*

parameters:
- name: path
  type: string
  default: 'dist/*.whl'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.10'
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.10'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    pip install twine keyring artifacts-keyring
    pip install wheel
    pip install twine
    python -m pip install --upgrade build setuptools twine
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: |
    python -m build
  displayName: 'Build Python Package'

- task: TwineAuthenticate@1
  inputs:
    artifactFeed: 'MyApp/myapp-packages'
  displayName: 'Authenticate Twine'

- script: |
    echo $(PYPIRC_PATH)
    python -m twine upload -r myapp-packages --repository-url https://myapp-packages:$(System.AccessToken)@pkgs.dev.azure.com/kngwin/MyApp/_packaging/myapp-packages/pypi/upload/ --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) dist/*
  displayName: 'Upload Package'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a .pypirc file in your home directory to store your token for authentication when uploading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pypi?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#authenticate-with-azure-artifacts

Or, define the Authentication token directly into the package URL:

```
python -m twine upload -r insite-packages --repository-url https://<your-feed-name>:$(System.AccessToken)@pkgs.dev.azure.com/kngwin/MyApp/_packaging/myapp-packages/pypi/upload/ --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) dist/*
```

Make sure your build service account has "Contributor" permission in the target Feed.

[image]

Comment: Hi Kim,

Thank you for your time and reply. I've done as you suggested, trying both methods, but it's still asking me to open the device login page and enter in a code.

Please see edit above and advise further?

Thank you, and I appreciate your help in all of this.

Answer (score 1):

---

**MY SOLUTION:**

I was able to get it working by doing the following:

I removed the "repository url" and ran it like so and it worked:

```
- script: |
    python -m twine upload --verbose -r myapp-packages --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) dist/*
  displayName: 'Upload Package'
```